# Got error "No implementation for play.cache.SyncCacheApi was bound" when using guice and pac4j

Tags: guice, pac4j

Here is the code I ran:

```
package org.example;

import com.google.inject.*;
import org.pac4j.core.context.session.SessionStore;
import org.pac4j.play.store.PlayCacheSessionStore;
import org.pac4j.play.store.PlaySessionStore;
import play.cache.SyncCacheApi;

class AuthModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        System.out.println("here");
        final PlayCacheSessionStore playCacheSessionStore = new PlayCacheSessionStore(getProvider(SyncCacheApi.class));
        bind(SessionStore.class).toInstance(playCacheSessionStore);
        bind(PlaySessionStore.class).toInstance(playCacheSessionStore);
    }

}

class AuthenticationController {
    @Inject
    private PlaySessionStore _playSessionStore;

    public void printSomething() {
        System.out.println(_playSessionStore);
    }
}

class GuiceTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new AuthModule());
        AuthenticationController authenticationController = injector.getInstance(AuthenticationController.class);
        authenticationController.printSomething();
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

The dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.pac4j:pac4j-oidc:4.5.7"
    implementation "com.typesafe.play:play-guice_2.12:2.8.18"
    implementation "com.google.inject:guice:4.2.3"
    implementation "com.typesafe.play:play-cache_2.12:2.8.18"
    implementation "org.pac4j:play-pac4j_2.12:9.0.2"
}
```

I referenced the code from play-pac4j-java-demo `play-pac4j-java-demo/app/modules/SecurityModule.java` (https://github.com/pac4j/play-pac4j-java-demo/blob/master/app/modules/SecurityModule.java).
I created the PlayCacheSessionStore instance, tried using Guice to ingest, but got the following error:

```
1) No implementation for play.cache.SyncCacheApi was bound.
  at org.example.AuthModule.configure(GuiceTester.java:14)

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.throwCreationExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:554)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:161)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:108)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:87)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:69)
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:59)
    at org.example.GuiceTester.main(GuiceTester.java:32)
```

I'm new to pac4j and guice, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure here, but I don't see any real cache implementation in your dependencies: can you try adding this dependency:

```java
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  caffeine
)
```

?